# Use JSON data set as seed for EntityFramework database

Tags: c#, json, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to expose static objects using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` in a `.netcoreapp 2.1`.

The data I want to expose is in a .json file, and I can deserialize it without any issue into its corresponding c# classes.

Here's a sample of the structure : https://pastebin.com/SKCKsDJi

For the sake of clarity i suggest you read it using your [favourite json reader](https://www.google.com/search?q=json%20online%20reader&oq=json%20online%20reader&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.2071j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

And here are the c# version of those objets :

```
public class FoodItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FoodType Type { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public bool IsVegetarian { get; set; }
}

public class FoodType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Lets keep it simple though, there are `ingredients`, `types` and `items`, items are basically sandwiches, which are of a certain type and contain a list of ingredients. All 3 have id's to match them. This is where my problem lies, or so I think.

Everything works fine if I'm just using "Types" for example, in my dbcontext. As soon as I try to add either ingredients or items, or all 3 (which I need, but baby steps), I have the following error.

`InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Ingredient' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.`

This is caused when :

```
    public EatupController(EatupContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        var completeModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EatUpDataModel>(EatUpDataSet.Complete);

        _context.Types.AddRange(completeModel.Types);   //Works
        _context.Ingredients.AddRange(completeModel.Ingredients);   //Crashes here.
        //If removed, all is fine but data is incomplete


        //_context.Types.AddRange(completeModel.Types);  //Unused
        //_context.Items.AddRange(completeModel.Items);  //Unused

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I don't understand why it's complaining about duplicate ID's, because they're all identical. Except, when I'm referencing the ingredient X in an item, obviously some items will use ingredients used by other items (many sandwiches have tomatoes). But surely that type of relation is allowed.

At first I had id's starting at 0 for all different types of objets, so ingredients ranged from 0 to about 100, items from 0 to 60, and types from 0 to 7. But since I had that error I edited all Id's and I still have the error, which is very confusing.

From what I read, this might also be due to using the context in different threads but this is not the case. If I remove the line that crashes, it stops crashing and I can see the data in the context correctly. In this case, only the types. If I add only the items or the ingredients in the context, it crashes for the same reason, just in another object (ingredient or item).

Where should I go from here? I don't even have a bad solution I could try to implement. My worst idea was to manually change the Id's (which is silly to me, it should work with the older ones), but even that failed.

Comment: Do the `Types` contain child objects that somehow refer to `Ingredients`?

Comment: No, both ingredients and types contain "id" and "name".
And none of them are equal.
But even that I would disagree with, I would like that the id's of my ingredients start at 0 and my types too. In my SQL, my tables always start at zero, even if other tables start at zero.

Comment: You can look at the json in the pastebin to be ultra clear about the object relations, they're mapped exactly the same in C#

Comment: So the JSON contains some duplicates by the way. the `items` list also has the ingredients there too, so that would be a problem. Also, why do the ingredients start at zero? Not a problem but it's strange as it can hide "empty" values later on.

Comment: They start at zero for no reason, it could start at 1 or 764, I just assumed 0 was a good start for an ID. I can change that (although editing the json is a pain :D).
The items contain the ingredients because they "should", like their real life counterpart. How should I structure my objects if I want my `items` to be made of various `ingredients`, if not by having a list of those `ingredients` as a property of `item` ? I dont want it to be duplicated, but I don't see how else it could be made.

Comment: You should have an intermediate table to link ingredients and items, I'd add them as a distinct entity.

Comment: If two food items share an ingredient, your JSON deserializer will give you two different Ingredient entities with the same key.

Comment: Okay I understand the issue, but how can I manage that situation then ? Two food items will very often share ingredients. Should I re-arrange my json or is there a way to "parse it better" ?